# How to set a group of dropdowns on a bootstrap page to use the same width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a page on a ASP.NET site which uses Bootstrap (v3.3.6). I am using Razor syntax to place a dropdown select input on the page, the issue I'm having is that the width of the boxes appears to be set by the length of the options within. I'd like instead to have all these dropdowns the same width. I understand I may be able to specify a specific or min/max width in CSS to resolve this but was wondering if there is any combination of the Bootstrap classes that could achieve this in a more dynamic manner?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssigneeTeam, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5 col-sm-12 text-left" })
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AssigneeTeam,
     EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(WebApplication1.Models.RequestBase.AssigneeTeams)),
 new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssigneeTeam, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Priority, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5 col-sm-12 text-left" })
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Level,
     EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(WebApplication1.Models.RequestBase.PriorityLevels)),
 new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Priority, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AffectedComponent, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5 col-sm-12 text-left" })
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AffectedComponent,         EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(WebApplication1.Models.RequestBase.EstateComponents)), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AffectedComponent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5 col-sm-12 text-left" })
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type,
     EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(WebApplication1.Models.RequestBase.ChangeType)),new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[This is a screenshot of the result, as you can see the dropdowns vary in width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acp1V.png)

Comment: if i use a raw HTML code based on your output all selects have the same 100% width https://jsfiddle.net/cx9f5k5j/ . What exactly does your code generate with @Html.DropDownListFor... ? is it <select class="form-control input-sm"> ? do you use any select js plugins instead?

Comment: @GL.awog The generated HTML is per below:
    <select data-val="true" data-val-required="The AssigneeTeam field is required." htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control input-sm }" id="AssigneeTeam" name="AssigneeTeam"><option value="0">Business Support</option>
    <option value="1">Marketing</option>
    </select>

I had some css that was providing a bit of styling on the select so I've taken that out but it hasn't changed the widths.

Comment: that's not the final raw code. seems like your select doesnt get assigned class = "form-control input-sm" . Form-control class gives 100% width.

Comment: @GL.awog thank you for pointing that out to me! Once you said that I managed to trace it back to find the cause in my code. I've posted the full explanation as an answer below to provide closure on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @GL.awog for pointing me in the right direction with this I noticed that the issue I had stemmed from me wrapping the `new { @class = "form-control input-sm" }` with `new { htmlAttributes = ...`. This was in the `@Html.DropDownListFor(...)` Razor code block. Doing this meant the Bootstrap classes were not being interpreted and so the select was not displaying in the manner expected.

The usage of htmlattributes enables us to specify attributes on the HTML as a shortcut to creating editor templates and is explained in further detail here: http://cpratt.co/html-editorfor-and-htmlattributes/